# Cannot access secondary GPU

Tags: release-freya

Having troubles with integrate and discrete gpu on Freya using bumblebee.

It gives me  "Could not load GPU driver" error

Modules are load in kernel and nvidia driver are installed.

Anyone could help?

Comment: How did you install the bumblebee driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anywone having same issue, looks like it was an error when install dkms, incompatible with the kernel version.

Solved unnistalling everything of nvidia propietary drivers and configuring bumblebee to use nouveau kernel drivers